# Show Map/Reduce script error on a SuiteLet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have created a Suitelet which runs a Map Reduce script when user Submits it. 
I am able to show messages such as Completed, Failed or In Progress using `task.checkStatus(taskId)`.

Is there anyway that I can also show the MR erros in UI, in case that M/R fails?

Probably I could use Custom Records to create the errors and then show them (too havy) or send the errors via email. But if there is a way I would prefer showing them directly to the user.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do this:

1. Log the errors normally. 
   Periodically while the m/r is running run a search on the script logs filtering the results on the script and deployment.
2. Accumulate the errors and create a `summarize` phase in the m/r and email the results to the person who ran the m/r. Netsuite’s example m/r has a hint about how to do that

Comment: Yeah that one way to do it. What I am asking is if there is a way to show them on UI. 
As I said this MR script is being created by a SL. I want the errors to appear there if possible.

Comment: Yes. In the m/r log the errors. Then in the suitelet periodically search for the errors in the script log and display them.